# Is LLVM compiler-rt installed on my Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, llvm

I'm building CoreFoundation on Ubuntu 14.04.  A prerequisite is compiler-rt.  I've installed clang 3.4 and llvm from repositories.   But I can't figure out if compiler-rt is installed.  I find no sign of it.  Also, I can't find any info on in which package it might exist.

How can I tell?  and/or  Is it possible to installed compiler-rt from repositories, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.  It's in libblocksruntime-dev